# Using sibling combinator with svg and :focus

Tags: html, css, svg

I just learned about the sibling combinator in CSS and I'm trying to shift some of JavaScript operations into CSS but I'm having difficulty.

```
<div class="box">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64"><path d="m64 50-4-8h-6v-4c0-1.1-0.9-2-2-2h-18c-1.1 0-2 0.9-2 2v16l2 2h2.536c-0.341 0.588-0.536 1.271-0.536 2 0 2.209 1.791 4 4 4s4-1.791 4-4c0-0.729-0.196-1.412-0.536-2h11.073c-0.341 0.588-0.537 1.271-0.537 2 0 2.209 1.791 4 4 4s4-1.791 4-4c0-0.729-0.196-1.412-0.537-2h2.537v-6zm-10 0v-6h4.146l3 6h-7.146z"/></svg>
<div><input type="text"></div>
<div><input type="text"></div>
<div><input type="text"></div>
</div>
```

I'm able to change the color of my svg image with:

```
path{fill:#f00}
```

However, I'd only like to change the color if an input in .box is focused.

```
.box svg path~.box div input:focus{fill:#f00}
```

Since they are not directly siblings, I used prefixes to bring them to the same level.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common
>   parent.

So the involved elements must have the same parent. This should not be confused with "same ancestor". `.box` is an ancestor of `path` and `input:focus` but is not either's parent.

Because of this, you usually don't specify the whole CSS "path" on the right. This also means you can't pair an element inside `svg` with an element outside.

You also have the order backwards. Assuming it worked at all, `fill` would be applied to `input:focus`.

Moving things around to make it work and taking advantage of some other tricks gives something like this:

```
input {
  display:block;
}
.box input:focus ~ svg {
  fill:#f00;
}
```

```
<div class="box">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64"><path d="m64 50-4-8h-6v-4c0-1.1-0.9-2-2-2h-18c-1.1 0-2 0.9-2 2v16l2 2h2.536c-0.341 0.588-0.536 1.271-0.536 2 0 2.209 1.791 4 4 4s4-1.791 4-4c0-0.729-0.196-1.412-0.536-2h11.073c-0.341 0.588-0.537 1.271-0.537 2 0 2.209 1.791 4 4 4s4-1.791 4-4c0-0.729-0.196-1.412-0.537-2h2.537v-6zm-10 0v-6h4.146l3 6h-7.146z"/></svg>
</div>
```